# How to prove this summation?

Tags: summation

How to prove this summation without mathematical induction? Thanks a lot!
I can't figure out a way to reduce n to $\sqrt{n}$.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor = 2\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor ^2
$$

---

**UPD: I think I got one proof, thanks to all, especially peter's idea.**

let f(n) denote the numbers of n, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)$, because $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor$ can be viewed as $i,2i...\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor i \leq n$, i's multiple, we can also consider i as some number's divisors, it appears the same time which is $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor$.

then we calcuate f(n), if $a\vert n$ then $\frac{n}{a}\vert n$, it's one to one, then $f(n)=2\sum_{i\leq \sqrt{n}, i\vert n}1$. But there is one exception, that is when n is a square number, it counted twice, let's denote g(n)=1 if n is square, else g(n)=0. then:

$$
f(n) = 2\sum_{i\leq \sqrt{n}, i\vert n}1 - g(n)
$$

thus we get

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2\sum_{j\leq \sqrt{i}, j\vert i}1 - g(i))
=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\sum_{j\leq \sqrt{i}, j\vert i}1) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}g(i)
$$

we do subscript changing and got:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\sum_{j\leq \sqrt{i}, j\vert i}1)
=\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\sum_{i\geq j^2,j\vert i}1
=\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\sum_{k=j}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{j} \right\rfloor}1
=\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{j} \right\rfloor-j+1)\\
=\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor-\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}(i-1)
=\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor(\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor-1)/2
$$

so we got:

$$
2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\sum_{j\leq \sqrt{i}, j\vert i}1) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}g(i)
=2(\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor(\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor-1)/2)-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor\\
=2\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor ^2
$$

Comment: thx! I changed to floor

Comment: Can you think about this in terms of counting multiples of $i$ less than $n$?

Comment: Ah, yes! I got one. consider f(n) as the number of divisors of n, then if ab=n,a<=b, then a<=$\sqrt{n}$ , so $f(n)=2\sum_{i\leq \sqrt{n},i\vert n}1$ if n is not a square, else we should minus 1, which lead to the $-\sqrt{n}$, then sum it up we get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can see why this holds from the graph of the hyperbola:

> [image]

The sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor$$ counts the area under this curve while the sum $$2\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor ^2$$ counts the area below the square and one leg of the hyperbola twice, then takes away the square which was double counted.

---

The prove this notice we can write the sum as a sum over divisors $$\sum_{i \le n} d(i) = \sum_{i \le n} \sum_{d|i} 1 = \sum_{dk \le n} 1 = \sum_{i \le n}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor$$

it is the second last form which shows the same symmetry we noticed geometrically, so we can use that one to prove the identity: Just split the sum up like this $$\sum_{dk \le n}  = \sum_{\begin{array}{c}d \le \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor \\ dk \le n\end{array}}+\sum_{\begin{array}{c}k \le \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor \\ dk \le n\end{array}}-\sum_{\begin{array}{c}d \le \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor \\ k \le \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor\end{array}}$$ and we are done

Comment: Thanks! Using graph is brilliant! It makes it easy to see.